# Entity Framework 6.0 ChangeTracker.Entries non public members

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project, I am overriding entity saveChanges() method as below.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added || p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified))
        {
           // Logs
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But, ChangeTracker.Entries() says non public members . It is not an error but  I must take the values for logging. Because ChangeTracker.Entries() count=0 , I can't do anything. I am using Entityframework 6.0 
Thnks.

Comment: What do you mean by says non public members? I tried your code it works without a problem.... what is the issue here?

Comment: When I am debugging, It does not enter into foreach statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework tracks changes only on public properties as they are being mapped to database fields.

If you want to track changes on objects you need to change public properties then.

You should also call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` before using `ChangeTracker.Entries()` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges(v=vs.113).aspx).

**EDIT:** Added comment about `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`

Comment: What do you mean with 'you need to change public properties then.'?

Comment: Only entries which are 1. public properties and 2. have an active mapping with a database field are checked during ChangeTracker.Entries(). Another point: You should always add a call to `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` to find all changes. I've updated the answer accordingly.